# WD black sshd cannot be found in BIOS without OS

Tags: hard-drive

My laptop leaves space for  only one disc, and I bought the WD black SSHD to replace my previous corrupted disc. However, I cannot find the hard drive in BIOS, while safety check shows it is perfectly here.

I looked up on Google and here it says http://techreport.com/news/24783/wd-explains-hybrid-tech-behind-black-sshds the driver's running under windows instead of shipped with firmware like seagate. Does that mean, without software, I'm unable to run this disc?

Model: WD10S12X

Comment: Can you add the exact model number?

Comment: @Techpumpkin_WD now it's here.

Comment: @knh170 - The production code isn't the model number.

Comment: @Ramhound code is correct.

Comment: The cache capabilities of that drive will work regardless if you install Intel's Smart Response Technology or not.  The SSHD isn't *software derived* either.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't quite get that, but how do you suggest to make my laptop detect it? I couldn't do anything unless the disc runs.

Comment: You should be able to run the disc without installing the software. Have checked if WD DLG DOS version detects it? You can download it here: http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=P6bO9h

Comment: @knh170 - You asked if you need special software to use the drive, the answer to that question, is absolutely no, you do not need special software, to use the drive in question. I answered the question *you* and attempted to clarify your knowledge on a subject.

Comment: @Techpumpkin_WD this requires dos environment but I couldn't boot even with liveCD, failing with internal drive not found problem.

Comment: I see. In this case I would test the drive on a different system to see if it works. You can also double check if all the cables are plugged in properly and securely. Have you tested your old HDD on a different system to confirm it is working? If you can enter BIOS try switching between Sata Mode AHCI / IDE.

Comment: @Techpumpkin_WD my old disc can be read under ubuntu, but not windows. And I just tested the old one, which can be detected with the laptop. But if I switch to linux with the WD black, boot option doesn't provide "boot with CD". And, there is no other option except for AHCI.

Comment: At this point you just need to test the drive in another system. It might be DOA.